# PHP Splitting multiple Strings

Tags: php

I have a text file: 'bookdata' with the following structure:

```
abcd@yahoo.com:1:20.30
efgh@hotmail.com:4:5.05
 ...
```

email : total no. of books : total books read.

My problem is to separate each part of the various strings using an associative array as follows:

```
 +-----------------------------------------------+
 |                     yahoo.com                 |
 +---------------+------------------+------------+
 | abcd@yahoo.com |         1        |     20.30 |

 | efgh@yahoo.com |         4        |      5.05 |
 +---------------+------------------+------------+
```

My approach so far is as follows:

I have a function makeArray() that has the data from the read txt file:

```
public function makeArray()
{
    $readTxtData = $this->read('bookdata');
    //Get the domain from data....
    $domain = preg_split("~[A-Za-z](.*?)@~", $readTxtData);

    return $domain;
}
```

The result:

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => yahoo.com:7:8.35

        [2] => hotmail.com:4:5.59
)
```

The array should look like this:

```
 Array
(
    [yahoo.com]
        (
            [0]
                (
                    [0] => abcd@yahoo.com
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 8.35
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => efgh@yahoo.com
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 8.36
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => oyp@yahoo.com
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 13.42
                )
        ).....
```

Thanks.

Comment: show how should look the final array structure(not tabular image)?

Comment: Please see above. I think it should look like this so that I can then iterate and display it in the web page.

Comment: this `{[(yahoo.com) (abcd@yahoo.com, 1 , 20.30) ...` is invalid notation. It wouldn't get such structure

Comment: FYI, that's not a valid array structure.

Comment: I've corrected it now. Thanks @Rajdeep Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the fact that you're reading the entire text file data in `$readTxtData` variable, **the solution** to your problem would be like this,

```
public function makeArray(){
    $readTxtData = $this->read('bookdata');

    $lines = explode("\n", $readTxtData);
    $result = array();
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $components = explode(":", $line); 
        $domain = explode("@", $components[0]);
        $result[$domain[1]][] = $components;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Algorithm:**

1. Create an empty array named `$result`.

   ```
   $result = array();
   ```
2. Loop through each of the lines of text file i.e. `$lines` using `foreach` loop and do step 3 to 5.

   ```
   foreach($lines as $line){
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Explode each line i.e. `$line` to get all three components, such as *email*, *total no. of books* and *total books read* in an array i.e. `$components`, like this:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [0] => abcd@yahoo.com
       [1] => 1
       [2] => 20.30
   )
   ```

   This step is performed by the following statement,

   ```
   $components = explode(":", $line);
   ```
4. Explode `$components[0]` string to get all domain related components, such as *user name* and *domain name* in an array i.e. `$domain`, like this:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [0] => abcd
       [1] => yahoo.com
   )
   ```

   This step is performed by the following statement,

   ```
   $domain = explode("@", $components[0]);
   ```
5. Now use the domain name i.e. `yahoo.com` as key in `$result` array and append `$components` array to it accordingly.

   ```
   $result[$domain[1]][] = $components;
   ```
6. Finally return the `$result` array.

   ```
   return $result;
   ```

Here are the necessary references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: That was perfect!!. Many thanks. Can you explain a little if you have a couple of lines to spare or give me some reference to this? Thanks.

Comment: @ASO I've updated my answer. I've added the alogrithm and the necessary references.

Comment: Cool.Thanks again mate!!